# The function is not running well while using a global variable

Tags: javascript, html, global-variables, local-variables

I am trying to make a probability finder to take some random numbers and find the probability of a number from the array of random numbers. I have the following code :

```js
/*********************Select Random Number**********************/

//Number of cases
var nOC = document.getElementById("noc").value;

function rollDice() {

  //Number of trials
  let nOT = document.getElementById("not").value;

  //Empty Array to be filled
  let array = [];

  //Loop which pushes random numbers in the empty array
  for (let i = 1; i <= nOT; i++) {
    array.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * nOC));
  }

  //Display results in a paragraph
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Your random numbers are " + array;
}

/*********************Get Probability**************************/

function getProbabilityOf() {

  //Probability of...
  let oP = document.getElementById("op").value;

  //Check if the number is out of range. If no, then find the probability of given number
  if (oP >= noC) {
    alert("This number is out of the range of possible outcomes that you have selected in step 1");
  } else {
    //Some code here
  }
}
```

```html
<!---------------------------Intro------------------------------>
<h1>Probability Finder</h1>
<hr/>
<p>With our probability finder, you can easily choose the number of possible cases and select the number of times you want to select a random case each time from the total cases and finally find the empirical probability of and case you want from the selected
  total number of cases.</p>

<!---------------------------Step 1------------------------------>
<h3><span class="bold">Step 1 :</span>Select total number of cases:</h3>

<select id="noc">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<!---------------------------Step 2---------------------------->
<h3><span class="bold">Step 2 :</span>Select total number of trials</h3>

<select id="not">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="70">70</option>
  <option value="80">80</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>

<!----------------------------Step 3----------------------------->
<h3><span class="bold">Step 3 :</span>Get random numbers by experiment</h3>

<button onclick="rollDice()">Get random numbers</button>

<p id="para"></p>
<!----------------------------Step 4----------------------------->


<h3><span class="bold">Step 4 :</span>Get probability of a particular number</h3>


<select id="op" onchange="getProbabilityOf()">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Before declaring the second function, nOC was declared local to function rollDice. But after I declared the next function, I needed to access it to complete step 4 (as mentioned in the code snippet). So I removed the variable nOC from the function and declared it globally(as shown in the code snippet).
The problem is that after declaring the variable as a global variable, none of the function was able to access it. 
To resolve this problem, I rechecked the syntax many times but found no problems with it (as per my knowledge). I tried changing the type of the variable from let to var and const but still, the problem was not solved.
What could be the problem? As a new newbie in the field of coding, I know that small mistakes are made by me, but it is very important for me to know my mistakes and fix them.

Comment: `input.value` is always a string. You are working with the string `"3"`, not with the number `3`. You need to convert the values to numbers `let nOT = +document.getElementById("not").value`. Note that Typescript would tell you that (`let nOT:number = input.value` would tell you "Cannot assign string to number")

Comment: `var nOC = document.getElementById("noc").value;` but using as `if(oP >= noC)` **'O'** has a typo

Comment: The value is going to be set when the page loads. Changing it is not going to update `nOC` since it does not automatically update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers.

The error stems from the inline handlers. `onchange="getProbabilityOf()"` executes when the document renders. So after the page is loaded *the `onchange` attribute will have the value of whatever result `getProbabilityOf()` returned*. That won't be a javascript function I suspect.

Here are a few modifications to your code, making it work (technically). I have not checked if it's the right output, it's just some technical adjustments. Now you can use that as a base to continue your efforts.

[About event delegation...](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

Not related to the code, but to 'number of cases' and for fun: [What's a sample of size one worth](https://www.i-programmer.info/news/112-theory/4415-whats-a-sample-of-size-one-worth.html)?

```js
// store a reference to #noc
const nOC = document.querySelector("#noc");

// add event handlers (event delegation)
document.addEventListener("click", rollDice)
document.addEventListener("change",
  evt => {
    if (evt.target.id === "op") {
      return getProbabilityOf();
    }
  });


function rollDice(evt) {
  if (evt.target.tagName !== "BUTTON") { return; }
  
  //Number of trials
  const nOT = +document.querySelector("#not").value;
  const nocValue = +nOC.value;
  //                    ^ retrieve #nOC value here
  //Empty Array to be filled
  let array = [];

  //Loop which pushes random numbers in the empty array
  for (let i = 1; i <= nOT; i += 1) {
    array.push( Math.ceil(Math.random() * nocValue));
    
  }
  //Display results in a paragraph
  document.querySelector("#para").innerHTML = `Your random numbers are ${array}`;
}


/*********************Get Probability**************************/
function getProbabilityOf() {
  //Probability of...
  const oP = +document.querySelector("#op").value;

  //Check if the number is out of range. If no, then find the probability of given number
  if (oP >= +nOC.value) {
  //        ^ determine #nOC value here
    alert("This number is out of the range of possible outcomes that you have selected in step 1");
  } else {
    //Some code here
  }
}
```

```html
<!---------------------------Intro------------------------------>
<h1>Probability Finder</h1>
<hr/>


<p>With our probability finder, you can easily choose the number of possible cases and select the number of times you want to select a random case each time from the total cases and finally find the empirical probability of and case you want from the selected
  total number of cases.</p>

<!---------------------------Step 1------------------------------>
<h3><span class="bold">Step 1 :</span>Select total number of cases:</h3>
<select id="noc">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<!---------------------------Step 2---------------------------->
<h3><span class="bold">Step 2 :</span>Select total number of trials</h3>

<select id="not">
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="70">70</option>
  <option value="80">80</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select>

<!----------------------------Step 3----------------------------->
<h3><span class="bold">Step 3 :</span>Get random numbers by experiment</h3>

<button>Get random numbers</button>

<p id="para"></p>

<!----------------------------Step 4----------------------------->
<h3><span class="bold">Step 4 :</span>Get probability of a particular number</h3>

<select id="op">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well! It is working! Where can I get more information on the eventListener? I have not used it till now and I am new to it.

Comment: Hi @PraneetDixit, both links in the answer give more information about `eventListener`. Furthermore, check this [introduction](https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your script uses a DOM element and therefore must run after the DOM is loaded. You can do just use script just before closing `body` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Probability Finder</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!---------------------------Intro------------------------------>

    <h1>Probability Finder</h1>

    <hr />

    <p>
      With our probability finder, you can easily choose the number of possible
      cases and select the number of times you want to select a random case each
      time from the total cases and finally find the empirical probability of
      and case you want from the selected total number of cases.
    </p>

    <!---------------------------Step 1------------------------------>

    <h3><span class="bold">Step 1 :</span>Select total number of cases:</h3>

    <select id="noc">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <!---------------------------Step 2---------------------------->

    <h3><span class="bold">Step 2 :</span>Select total number of trials</h3>

    <select id="not">
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
      <option value="60">60</option>
      <option value="70">70</option>
      <option value="80">80</option>
      <option value="90">90</option>
      <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>

    <!----------------------------Step 3----------------------------->

    <h3><span class="bold">Step 3 :</span>Get random numbers by experiment</h3>

    <button onclick="rollDice()">Get random numbers</button>

    <p id="para"></p>

    <!----------------------------Step 4----------------------------->

    <h3>
      <span class="bold">Step 4 :</span>Get probability of a particular number
    </h3>

    <select id="op" onchange="getProbabilityOf()">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <script>
      /*********************Select Random Number**********************/

      //Number of cases
      var nOC = document.getElementById('noc')
      function rollDice () {
        //Number of trials
        let nOT = document.getElementById('not').value

        //Empty Array to be filled
        let array = []

        //Loop which pushes random numbers in the empty array
        for (let i = 1; i <= nOT; i++) {
          array.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * parseInt(nOC.value, 10)))
        }

        //Display results in a paragraph
        document.getElementById('para').innerHTML =
          'Your random numbers are ' + array
      }

      /*********************Get Probability**************************/

      function getProbabilityOf () {
        //Probability of...
        let oP = document.getElementById('op').value

        //Check if the number is out of range. If no, then find the probability of given number
        if (oP >= parseInt(nOC.value, 10)) {
          alert(
            'This number is out of the range of possible outcomes that you have selected in step 1'
          )
        } else {
          //Some code here
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but on running, it is considering the values Not a Number

Comment: @HimanshuPandey your code does not fix `"Uncaught ReferenceError: noC is not defined",`